# What is the correct format of the RegExp.prototype.test( ) method?

Tags: javascript

What is the correct syntax for `RegExp.prototype.test()`?
I tried this: `var testVar = nullFld.test(nameVal);` 
But it does not like it. 
I thought `testVar` would be true or false based on the comparison of `nullFld` and `nameVal`.

thanks
Joe B

Comment: you'll have to supply some context ... like some code (not just one line) to show what nullFld and nameVal actually are - is nullFld a regular expression object?

Comment: "it does not like it" -- *what does that mean*?

Answer (score 1):

`regexObj.test(str)`

For example

```
var re = /null/;
var testVar = re.test("null");
```

See [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)